# How do I pass Array in $router.push in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to pass data through function of VUE to a new page on click of a button. I tried doing this thing using the router method but i was not able to send the array it was just allowing me to send a string with it.

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "SalesInvoice",
    params: { SalesInvoice: this.stockmaster }
  });
```

this thing is not working beacuse the stockmaster is an array.

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "SalesInvoice",
    params: { SalesInvoice: "abc" }
  });
```

the same thing i did with string and it worked.
so is there any way of sending array to next page using vue method.

Comment: try sending JSON.stringify(this.stockmaster) and then parse it wherever you want to get it

Comment: how can we do this ? can you guide me with the code?

Comment: `this.$router.push({
    name: "SalesInvoice",
    params: { SalesInvoice: JSON.stringify(this.stockmaster ) }
  });`. And please read about `JSON.stringify` as well

Comment: thank you it really helped.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Please convert your comment into an answer so this question may be closed off

Comment: @MuhammadUsman You rock man, thaanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, I would not recommend to use `JSON` as URL parameters, but rather use `query` parameters instead. If you want to send data from one request to the next, it is common to use query parameters instead of route parameters.

In your case, change the code to

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "SalesInvoice",
    query: { SalesInvoice: "abc" }
  });
```

You can then change your route definition to be something like this

```
{
  path: 'sales-invoice', 
  name: 'SalesInvoice',
}
```

See, the path does not have any more `:SalesInvoice` in it. The route parameter is not necessary anymore, since you are now giving the data to the new route via query parameters.
You can use as many query parameters as you like (actually, as many as the max length of a URL allows) without any need to define them in the route definition. This gives you more flexibility.

You can access query parameters similarly to route parameters by using `this.$route.query.SalesInvoice`.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding my comment as an answer so others can get it easily in the future.

When you are trying to pass an array, object or array of objects to the router, you should first `stringify` your data with `JSON.stringify` and the pass it to the router. And then you can access it and parse it back to `JSON` with `JSON.parse`. For the particular case above, something like following should be done

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "SalesInvoice",
    params: { SalesInvoice: JSON.stringify(this.stockmaster) }
  });
```

Comment: very helpful indeed.